# ver usuarios registrados con la api de google

Tags: php, aplicación-web

me parece muy interesante e importante esto de inicio de sesión usando cuenta de  Google, me pregunto si una ves que este la aplicación registrada en la api de Google y se este validando estos datos para efectivamente redirigir a la pagina predestinada por el desarrollador, es posible las siguientes cosas=

•   Muestre  en una interfaz el total de los usuarios registrados  con cuenta de Google
•   Rol de administrador y de usuario usando esta misma validación de Google
•   Si el usuario realiza algún cambio por ejemplo en una aplicación que utiliza inicio de sesión con Google y esta tiene un crud, es posible que al ingresar o actualizar los datos de este crud quede registrado el correo o nombre del usuario de Google  del usuario que lo realizo o se complica por estar usando la api de Google.
si esto es posible, como puedo llevarlo acabo en php?

Comment: Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o [lo que ha investigado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/21) ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto. Por otro lado, quizás haga falta que repitas el [tour], la regla es una pregunta por publicación.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Que si es posible hacer todo lo que dices en la pregunta? Sí, probablemente. Google tiene bibliotecas escritas en los principales lenguajes (incluido PHP) para interactuar con sus API. Incluso si necesitas trabajar con más de una API lo puedes hacer para integrar todo lo necesario en cualquier contexto. Dicho eso, considera plantear tus preguntas en base a un problema concreto, mostrando código concreto y mensajes de error concretos si fuera el caso. Tal y como está  pregunta ahora, todo se basa en opiniones.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la pregunta está mal redactada. En muchas partes pareciera basarse en opiniones. (cuando en  realidad sólo la última frase cae en ello). Voy a responderla porque alguna vez me pregunté lo mismo y no encontré una explicación conceptual que me ayudara. A continuación te dejo algunos puntos clave:

##### Flujo normal vs Flujo google (aplica a otros oauth también)

Vamos a decir que, cuando tus usuarios inician sesión, son enviados a su perfil de usuario (que es como lo que hace facebook)

**En el flujo normal** tu servidor tiene un endpoint `/login` donde recibe peticiones para iniciar sesión. Si estuviéramos en los zapatos del servidor, describiríamos que el login es

1. una petición POST al endpoint /login
2. en cuyo body viene una tupla usuario/contraseña
3. donde esa tupla calza con un usuario de la base de datos
4. le genero una sesión al usuario que hizo la petición
5. lo mando a su perfil

Para que esto funcione obviamente hay un paso previo, porque tuviste que armar inicialmente un formulario de registro donde el usuario llena sus datos incluyendo email y password y tú los almacenas para autenticarlo en el futuro.

**En el flujo con google** el servidor experimenta el login como

1. Una petición al endpoint `/google/callback`  (por ejemplo)
2. En cuyo query string viene un parámetro  `code` (ej /google/callback?code=QWERTYUASDF)
3. El cual no corresponde a nada contra lo que yo pueda contrastar
4. Pero si se lo envío a google me responderá con un token de usuario
5. Se procesa ese token
6. Le creo una sesión al visitante
7. lo envío a su perfil

El token que te manda Google a cambio del `code` es un array con tres llaves importantes

- `access_token` se usa para interactuar con las APIs de Google
- `refresh_token` se usa para renovar el access token cuando éste caduque luego de una hora. No lo necesitarás si usas Google sólo al momento del login
- `id_token` Es un [JWT](https://jwt.io/) y puedes usarlo para verificar si el usuario viene realmente de google y no es un impostor

Como el flujo con google también termina en "el usuario es enviado a su perfil" necesitamos que ese perfil exista. Dicho de otra manera, por mucho que venga de google lo más probable es que quieras generarle una fila en tu tabla de usuarios igualmente.

Acá no existe ese paso previo donde el usuario se inscribió, eso lo haces tú del lado del servidor, en el paso 5. Utilizando el `access_token` puedes pedirle a Google los datos del usuario, porque hasta ahora no los tienes. Harías algo como (ejemplo con laravel pero es igual con Guuzle en general)

```
    $response= Http::withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
    ])->get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', [
        'prettyPrint' => 'false',
    ]);
```

En esa respuesta vendrá como mínimo el correo electrónico. Con éste puedes crear un registro en base de datos asignando un password arbitrario. El usuario que almacenas en este flujo debiera llevar una marca adicional señalando que viene de Google.

Si el usuario ya existe obviamente no le pisas su contraseña. Pero si no tenía la marca de "usuario google" se la agregas.

Si de ahí en adelante ese usuario quiere autenticarse con usuario y contraseña es cosa que cambie la contraseña arbitraria que le pusiste . Para eso seguirá el flujo normal de  "olvidé mi contraseña".

#### Respuesta a tus preguntas

> Muestre en una interfaz el total de los usuarios registrados con cuenta de Google

Es justamente lo último que puse. Les haces una marca a tus usuarios para poder contar después cuántos vienen de google. La interfaz la haces tú por tu cuenta.

> Rol de administrador y de usuario usando esta misma validación de Google

Tus usuarios son tuyos y les das el rol que quieras. Google sólo reemplaza el llenado de formulario inicial y la comparación de contraseña en los siguientes logins.

> Si el usuario realiza algún cambio por ejemplo en una aplicación que utiliza inicio de sesión con Google y esta tiene un crud, es posible que al ingresar o actualizar los datos de este crud quede registrado el correo o nombre del usuario de Google del usuario que lo realizo o se complica por estar usando la api de Google.

Si el crud es tuyo, todas las acciones del usuario que se persistan en la base de datos pueden llevar su id, que obtienes de la sesión activa.

Google en ningún caso reemplaza tu almacenamiento de sesiones stateful.

Si el crud no es tuyo, sino de otro sitio que también usa autenticación con Google, tú no tienes como ver qué hacen tus usuarios allá adentro. Mal que mal, por mucho que sean usuarios (compartidos) tuyos, los CLAIMS que aceptaron son del tipo: "el sitio podrá ver mi correo electrónico" y no "el sitio lo administra un stalker".

> si esto es posible, como puedo llevarlo acabo en php?

Esta es la parte basada en opiniones. Sólo cabe aconsejar leer muchos tutoriales y usar [PHP API CLient](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). Algunos artículos útiles podrían ser

- https://www.webdew.com/blog/login-with-google-in-laravel
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/socialite

La mayor parte de las guías para integrar google auth no ahondan en el paso previo, que es crear una App en Google Cloud Console. Esta guía, cuyo propósito en realidad es integrarse con google drive, la tengo en mis favoritos desde hace mucho

- https://gist.github.com/sergomet/f234cc7a8351352170eb547cccd65011

##### Pero por qué se menciona Laravel, si el OP no dijo que usara Laravel

Porque si no se especifica, yo asumiré que tenemos PHP 7+, composer y esta vez fui un poco más allá.